# SelectNode Return Null in Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I saw a lots of similar posts, both of them talk about SelectSingleNode return null. I'm not quite sure my problem was related to that. Perhaps I had some problems which I could not figure out. Here my codes :

```
string url = "https://www.google.com/#q=nothing";    
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
web.Load(url);
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='content']");
if (nodes != null) {
    foreach(HtmlNode item in nodes) {
        if (item != null) {
            string s = item.InnerText;
            listView1.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("Nothing found here");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no `<div>` tags with class equal to `content`, then nothing is found and you have `null`. That's by design.

UPDATE: You are not loading data into `HtmlDocument`. You have `doc` instance which is not related for data you are loading. Use document which is returned by `Load` method:

```
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
```